# CSS incompatibility with Google Chrome

Tags: html, css

I have designed a login/register page that works flawlessly in Firefox but encounters an irritating bug in Chrome.

Here is the page in firefox:
[image]

And in Chrome:
[image]

The CSS for the grey 'section' boxes is:

```
.section{
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
display: inline-block;
padding: 20px;
margin-right: 30px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
max-width: 300px;
height: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:top` to your rules:

```
.section{
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
display: inline-block;
padding: 20px;
margin-right: 30px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
max-width: 300px;
height: 400px;
vertical-align:top;
}
```

The default vertical alignment of inline elements is baseline.